# VS Code not finding packages

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-code

Just started using VS Code for the first time (so far only used Visual Studio).
I'm going through an EF Core tutorial.

I installed all the necessary packages (or I thought so), but it still doesn't recognise then. I'm setting up my Data Access later, and doesn't recognise DbContext.

IntelliSense at the moment isn't working properly, but I thought I'd fix that later since I'm short on time.
So I manually added using statements:

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System; 
using System.Text;
```

.. but it doesn't recognise EntityFrameworkCore even ...

Here is what my csproj looks like:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net7.0</TargetFramework>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="7.0.5" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="7.0.5">
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="7.0.5" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.tools" Version="7.0.5">
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet" Version="2.0.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Data.Entity.Repository" Version="2.0.0.1" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

I installed them from the terminal with

```
dotnet install packag < package name >
```

and ran

```
dotnet reset
```

...

This was in a class library project.
Any advice on how to get this IDE to do its job will be appreciated! :)

Comment: Have you tried restarting VS Code after installing the packages? Does it work when you open the project in the regular Visual Studio?

Comment: Thanks, restarting VS Code did the job ... Still learning the peculiarities of this IDE ..

Answer (score 0):

Can you try execting below command from solution level which will try to get all the required packages.

```
dotnet restore
```

If you are using VS Code try using [C#](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-dotnettools.csharp) extension which will provide IntelliSense support.